# Redirecting to URL after submit button

Tags: asp.net

At this url http://localhost:9392/ClubLeague/StartMenu/161?type=ClubLeague I have a button that pops up a modal window with results. The modal window has a submit button that submits data from a DropdownListFor. After the submit button is clicked I wish to return to the same url - http://localhost:9392/ClubLeague/StartMenu/161?type=ClubLeague

however I get redirected to http://localhost:9392/ClubLeague/StartMenu?clubId=161

This is my RedirectToAction -   `return RedirectToAction("StartMenu", new { clubId });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change it;

```
return RedirectToAction("StartMenu", new { clubId });
```

to

```
return RedirectToAction("StartMenu", new { id = clubId,type = "ClubLeague" });
```

It redirects to user `/ClubLeague/StartMenu/161?type=ClubLeague`

Comment: Bullseye! Thanks!